# YouMax 2.0 change max-results

Tags: jquery-plugins, youtube-api

I found this plug-in called YouMax which embeds your youtube channel into your website, the only problem that I'm having with this plug-in is changing the amount of video results that are collected, it default is 25 videos I want to chane this to another value like 12 or 24.

http://www.codehandling.com/2013/03/youmax-20-complete-youtube-channel-on.html?m=1

Comment: i looked at the source. you will have a very difficult time navigating THAT

Comment: An option is already available to change the max results in the latest version - http://www.codehandling.com/p/codehandling-free-plugins.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be 3 sections to this plug-ins results: Featured, Uploads, and Playlists.

I edited the youmax.min.js file for the Featured section because it is the first results page that loads. My edit was very small. Essentially, I added the following:

```
&start-index=1&max-results=2
```

at the end of the string `var apiFeaturedPlaylistVideosURL`

This var is located inside the function: `function getFeaturedVideos(playlistId)`

You can change the result from 2 to 12 or whatever you want and that will be the max amount of results you get back from youtube.

Also- you can add this same argument (*&start-index=1&max-results=2*) to the Uploads and Playlists function in the youmax.min.js file if thats where you want to limit your results instead (or in addition to Featured section).

I created a copy of my edited youmax.min.js file in jsfiddle. My edit comes on line 152 on jsfiddle. Try downloading it and giving it a try. I hope it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/wCKKU/

Comment: thanks you this is what i was looking for and it really helped me, i was having problems navigating the code as it was on one line for me.

Comment: is it possible for you to change how the videos are dated as they seem to be dated in months and years, i want it to be dated to like youtube, day,month,year.

i think its the     "function getDateDiff"

Answer (score 0):

Youmax 2.0 (free version) has been upgraded which has the maxResults option builtin - http://demos.codehandling.com/youmax/home.html

You already get a "maxResults" option with the plugin and a "Load More" functionality.

Regarding the timestamps, you can try the [PRO version](http://demos.codehandling.com/youmax/pro.html) which has options to display relative timestamps (2 hours ago) or fixed timestamps (23 March 2016)

Cheers :)